# Having issue in conversation of UCMA with MS Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business, ucma, direct-line-botframework

I am working on MS Bot Framework Integration with UCMA(Skype For Business OnPremise aka SFB onPrimise) SDK.
I am using directline channel for connection and the Connection is successfully established between two, but when a dialog prompt with Yes, No options is returned From BOT to SFB, and when I send my answer as yes then BOT do not recognize it as my answer. It creates new conversation Id for every single statement. How to overcome this issue?

Below is my code from UCMA

```
        static DirectLineClient client = null;

        client = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.DirectLineClient("DirectLineSecretKey");
        botConversation = client.Conversations.NewConversation();

        string message = e.TextBody;
        Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.Models.Message msg = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.Models.Message
        {
            FromProperty = "AMOL",
            Text = message

        };
        await client.Conversations.PostMessageAsync(botConversation.ConversationId, msg);
        var messages = await client.Conversations.GetMessagesAsync(botConversation.ConversationId, watermark);
        InstantMessagingFlow instantMessagingFlow = (InstantMessagingFlow)sender;
        watermark = messages.Watermark;
        foreach (var m in messages.Messages)
        {
            if (m.FromProperty != "AMOL")
                instantMessagingFlow.BeginSendInstantMessage(m.Text, MyMethod, instantMessagingFlow);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same and it works for me. The problem in your code is, you create conversation id for each and every request and bot is considering the request as new fresh new request.

Let me know if you need any help on this.

Comment: Can you provide me working code OR help me to correct above code

Comment: The above code is from window service which connects with Skype for business server since it is windows service I will not be able to use session.